# Any shortcut to see the resource variable content in the source code?

Tags: android-studio, android-resources

In Android Studio, when we open a code or XML file, sometimes we can see the resource value as shown below i.e. `MockServer Experiment`. By clicking into it we'll be able to see that it is a resource string variable `@string/app_name`

[image]

My question is, how can I do the reverse (e.g. from the resource string variable, I can get it to show the value)? Aside from clicking into the resource file to see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>></kbd> works for me on my Ubuntu machine. To show a string value, you need to move the cursor to e.g. `@string/app_name` and press the shortcut.

Comment: Works on my mac when I click on it, then I press `Command >`

Answer (score 0):

if move typing cursor on it and use Ctrl+Shift+i, then a popup menu is opened and shows the definition.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ChAG.png)

Or You Can use Ctrl+Q

My Android Studio Version is 4.0

Comment: Doesn't work on my side. Both Ctrl+Shift+i and Ctrl+Q. Are you on the Windows machine? I'm on mac machine.

Comment: In mac you use 'Command+Y' instead of 'Control+Shift+i' and 'Control+J' instead of 'Control + Q' based on https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts